# How to configure grid-template-rows to 40px size middle rows only

Tags: css, css-grid

How to configure grid-template-rows to 40px size middle rows only? I've been searching and trying out different possible solutions only to discover none of them work.

I want a fixed header and footer. Then between those items, I want to display records out of a database at 40px height.

What I get as shown in the attachment, is the footer row does not render to 100px.[image]

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
  grid-auto-rows: 40px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
}
header {
  background: yellow;
}
record {
  background: cyan;
}
footer {
  background: green;
  color: white
}

<div class="container">
  <header class="grid">header</header>
  <record class="grid">record</record>
  <record class="grid">record</record>
  <record class="grid">record</record>
  <footer class="grid">footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: For a single column grid, you can even drop the grid-auto-X & grid-template-X : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/XWojKQB Make it simple and let at the most the browser do the job for you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(40px,max-content); /* 40px or more for all the rows */
  gap: 5px;
}
header,footer {
  height: 100px; /* 100px for footer and header  */
}
header {
  background: yellow;
}
record {
  background: cyan;
}
footer {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="grid">header</header>
  <record class="grid">record</record>
  <record class="grid">record</record>
  <record class="grid">record</record>
  <footer class="grid">footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: `grid-auto-rows: minmax(40px,auto) ;`   works too :)